# Upgraded from Phoenix 1.1.6 to 1.2 and now I get a CompileError

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I upgraded Phoenix from 1.1.6 to 1.2 and now I'm getting this weird CompileError.

```
(CompileError) web/views/main_view.ex:2: module Rejack.Router.Helpers is not loaded and could not be found
```

I compared a freshly generated Phoenix 1.2 project file by file to mine and I couldn't find any major differences.

The `view` part my `web.ex` looks like this:

```
def view do
  quote do
    require Logger

    use Phoenix.View, root: "web/templates"

    # Import convenience functions from controllers
    import Phoenix.Controller, only: [get_csrf_token: 0, get_flash: 2, view_module: 1]

    # Use all HTML functionality (forms, tags, etc)
    use Phoenix.HTML

    import Rejack.Router.Helpers
    import Rejack.ErrorHelpers
    import Rejack.Gettext
  end
end
```

and the view is also pretty standard

```
defmodule Rejack.MainView do
  use Rejack.Web, :view
end
```

Any idea what is causing this?

**Edit:**
The only major difference to a regular Phoenix project is that I'm not using `postgrex`, but `mongodb_ecto` (and therefor I'm stuck with `phoenix_ecto` 2.x).

Comment: That's weird, try to recompile phoenix maybe?

Comment: I tried it all :-/ deleted _build and deps.

Comment: do I get you right: the newly generated project works fine? also, not likely but did you check the owner and permissions of deps/phoenix/lib/phoenix/router/helpers.ex file?

Comment: The rights are fine. If I go back to 1.1.6 everything works like it should. It's really weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be down to using "forward" as a catch all in your routes that's pointing to a controller rather than a Plug.

```
forward "/", PageController, :index
```

If you do have that in your routes and you change it to use get "/*path" instead, that should fix the compilation errors for you.

```
get "/*path", PageController, :index
```

Comment: You Sir, are a lifesafer!